Using aftermarket lights as dipped beam
I regularly travel from Europe to the UK, and I'm looking for an alternative to having to apply stickers to my headlights every time I go.
Is it possible to use aftermarket lights as dipped beams?
To take a random example:

The angle of these can be adjusted. Is that adjustment enough to get a light that would be accepted as 'dipped beam'?
